# Convert WSDL to java in Spring-Tool-Suite?

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, salesforce, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to convert salesforce WSDL file to java in eclipse Spring-Tool-Suite.Is there any auto generate plugin in eclipse to do it.Help me out...pls

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it built-in? Just right click on the wsdl file and convert to client?

Else Apache has a tool for it too: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html